# Can not call a static panache method in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus

First Post. Absolute Beginner. Be kind

I am playing arround with quarkus and kotlin.

I have this kotlin entity class:

```
@Entity
data class Fruit (
        var name: String = "",
        var description: String = ""
) : PanacheEntity()
```

I have this Resource Class based on tutorials in Java:

```
@Path("/fruits")
@ApplicationScoped
public class FruitJResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Fruit> getAll() {
        return Fruit.listAll();
    }
}
```

Everything fine here, Fruit inherits from PanacheEntityBase, i can access listAll()

However, 
Same Class in Kotlin does not:

```
@Path("/fruits")
@ApplicationScoped
class FruitResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getAll(): List<Fruit> = Fruit.listAll()
}
```

Now i learned allready, that this is probably due kotlin not beeing able to inherit static methods from Super Class.
I read, that i should call the static method direct from the superclass, but this won't work here.

So I need a suggestion for a possible workaround.

Comment: Hello! Have you perhaps read https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4394 ?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution for `kotlin` and `scala` languages for now (1.4.1) is to use the Repository pattern :
see documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#solution-2-using-the-repository-pattern

This is due to referenced issue github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/4394.

So if using Kotlin, you simply have to define a new `FruitRepository`

```
@ApplicationScoped
class FruitRepository: PanacheRepository<Fruit> {

    fun all(): List<Fruit> = findAll(Sort.by("name")).list<Fruit>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus has released an extension which brings Kotlin support to panache (I think it is still in preview).

in Gradle (if you're using Gradle for your project) you'll need to add the dependencie `implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin'`

To define your "static" methods (Kotlin uses Companion objects to do stuff with static methods) you'll need to define a companion object like this:

```
@Entity
open class Category : PanacheEntityBase {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
lateinit var id: UUID

// ...

companion object : PanacheCompanion<Category, UUID> {
    fun findByName(name: String) = find("name", name).firstResult()
    fun findActive() = list("active", true)
    fun deleteInactive() = delete("active", false)
}
```

}

for more information you can check out the official docs:
https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin

Be warned if you use unit tests: at least for me the panache-mock extension is not working with the kotlin version of panache.